# FUSE getattr function hangs on lstat

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, fuse, stat

I am implementing a FUSE filesystem and as a first step have implemented only the `getattr` function. The code looks like this:

```
int test_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *statbuf){
    return lstat(path, statbuf);
}
```

The code works fine when I give any directory other than the directory on which the FUSE is mounted. For example, the above code works for `/home`, `/home/ubuntu/mnt/`, but hangs on `lstat` when path is `/home/ubuntu/mnt/fuse/` where `/home/ubuntu/mnt/fuse/` is the path passed to fuse_main. The code just hangs at `lstat`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getattr` implementation is stuck on an infinite loop, because `lstat` with FUSE paths invokes `test_getattr` again and again.

If your implementation is a wrapper to another filesystem, then you need to `lstat` the real path of the other filesystem.